# DotNetNuke: how to count modules in a pane on current page

Tags: dotnetnuke

Is there a way to **count** the visible **modules in** a specific **pane on** from the current page context?

I know in theory I could write a joined sql statement, but DotNetNuke offers a variety of objects that support this kind of operation.

This is for a DNN 4 site, but any hint also for DNN 5 is greatly appreciated.

Even the information if there is any module in the pane at all would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the **modules in a tab** with ModuleController.GetTabModules()

```
Imports DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules
...
Dim objModules As New ModuleController
Dim tabModules As Dictionary(Of Integer, ModuleInfo) = objModules.GetTabModules(TabId)
```

The keys of the dictionary are ModuleIDs and the values are ModuleInfo objects. You can also call the corresponding stored procedure `GetTabModules` to retrieve module data.

Now, `ModuleInfo` has a `PaneName` property that you would use to group the results, say, to another dictionary, and retrieve the counts from there:

```
    Dim result As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    For Each tabModule In tabModules.Values
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tabModule.PaneName) Then
            result(tabModule.PaneName) += 1
        End If
    Next
```

You probably also want to filter out the deleted modules:

```
    For Each tabModule In tabModules.Values _
        .Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PaneName)) _
        .Where(Function(x) Not x.IsDeleted)

        result(tabModule.PaneName) += 1

    Next
```

A list of distinct PaneNames for a tab can be retrieved with the stored procedure `GetTabPanes`. The corresponding method in the 4.9.5 codebase is implemented in the DataProvider:

```
Dim dr As IDataReader = DotNetNuke.Data.DataProvider.Instance().GetTabPanes(TabId)
```

Comment: That's it! In addition to solving my problem, it also contains a lot of other valuable ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you're wanting the count of which modules the current user can see, you'll want to call `ModuleController.GetTabModules` like [mika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409063/dotnetnuke-how-to-count-modules-in-a-pane-on-current-page/6411491#6411491) suggests, and filter by `PortalSecurity.HasNecessaryPermission` (or `ModulePermissionController.HasModuleAccess` in DNN 5)

```
var modules = from module in new ModuleController().GetTabModules(TabId).Values
              where !module.IsDeleted
                 && PortalSecurity.HasNecessaryPermission(SecurityAccessLevel.View, PortalSettings, module)
              group module by module.PaneName into paneCounts
              select new {
                  PaneName = paneCounts.Key,
                  Count = paneCounts.Count(),
              };
```

One further thing that you might need to do is check whether the module's `PaneName` matches a pane on the current tab (via `TabInfo.Panes` or `DataProvider.GetTabPanes`), otherwise, count it as `"ContentPane"`.

Comment: Thanks for great additional information, esp. PortalSecurity.HasNecessaryPermission!! Wish I could give you an "accepted" as well, but mika was first and solved the essentials for me (and has less reputation ;-) ). So an upvote must do.